# Different instances of store

Tags: reactjs, redux

guys.

I make project where we have tabs, like the browsers have. Each tab contains user searches with different settings and results of these searches. I can not find out the correct way to store this data.

I think, I need kind of several stores. Because I have only tabs which switch users between a kind of different applications, but inside one. In other case, I need to store data twice - remembering the current state, and collect old searches in some 'history' reducer.

Sorry, it is my first experience here, please help with it if anybody can.

Comment: You will always have only one store in redux. I think what you are trying to do here is have multiple _sections_ in your store so your components can subscribe to changes to only the sections they need. When you create your store, you use defaultState in parameter. That defaultState can contain those multiple sections and your reducers can then modified those sections separately.

Comment: I could write you a quick example of what it would like as an answer if you want.

Comment: @petithomme yes, please, if you can, I'd be grateful

Comment: @petithomme I want to notice that I can have, for example, "flights", 'formData' and other reducers like this. But I need to have multiple instances of this reducers. For example, my state object:
`
{
  mode: 'mobile',
  flightTabs:{
   id1: { flights: {..}, formData: {...} },
   id2: { flights: {..}, formData: {...} },
   idN: ...
  }
}
`

Comment: @petithomme I think you mean just multiple reducers which I can combine between each other?

Comment: Basically you'll have a data class for every _section_ of the store and a reducer with the same name as that class. The data classes will be combined in the `defaultState` of the store and the reducers will be combined in the `rootReducer` or whatever name you gave it in the store as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple *data* classes that contain variables and their values. These *data* classes can then be combined and used when creating the **store**.

This method allows you to have multiple sections in your store and each of your components can subscribe to the sections that they need. The Component will have the data of these sections he subscribed to and will re-render when one of these sections is updated.

Example of *data* classes:

`pageData.js`

```
export const pageData = {
  pageNumber: 1,
  pageSize: 30,
};
```

`userData.js`

```
export const userData = {
  language: 'English',
  timezone: 'ESTERN',
};
```

These classes are then combined when creating the store:

`store.js`

```
import pageData from .../pageData;
import userData from .../userData;

const defaultState = {
  pageData,
  userData,
};

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState));
```

Your reducer that needs to modify `pageData` will need to have the name `pageData` as well. Same thing for the `userData`.

After all this has been set up, you'll have to `mapStateToProps()` your components to the data you want them to subscribe to.

For example, if you want your `PageComponent.js` to only know the **pageData**, then in that component, you will use the method:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    pageData: state.pageData
  };
}
```

I would recommend looking into the [redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) to learn how to setup *mapStateToProps()*.

When all of this is done, you can `console.log(this.props)` and see that your data sections are there and well separated.

Comment: This might be a hard concept to grasp rapidly, if you have any questions or bugs, don't hesitate to write them here.